# How to check the class of an element and if the class exists make the parent visible

Tags: jquery, css

By default the parent element is not visible. However, depending on what is clicked a child element may contain a class named "selected". How do i test for this class and then if it exists make the whole list visible?

```
    <ul style="display: none;">
       <li class="selected">a</li>
       <li>b</li>
       <li>c</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: You said a class `selected` an it is an id in code. What's the point ?

Comment: my bad i fixed it in the code to say class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if( $('li').hasClass('selected')){
    $('li.selected').parent().show();
}​
```

Check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/WtRAU/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.selected').click(function(){$('li.selected').parents('ul:first').toggle()});
```

WORKING FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/tnCjn/

Comment: The point is that i'm hiding the secondary menu when its not selected. But if a secondary menu item is clicked from a page where its visible i want the menu to expand. :) This is usually easy but i'm building this in sharepoint.

Comment: i think you need this. check updated answer. .selected is the class which will remain same for the item which you want to show

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#selected').parent().show()
```

Comment: Can we search for elements if they are hidden? None of these are working for me.

Comment: @reub77 Yes, you can use `:hidden` selector.

Answer (score 0):

This shuold work for your code

```
$("#selected").parent().css("display", "");
```

But if you mean not Id, but class, then

```
$(".selected").parent().css("display", "");
```